# Where is the main method after converting a vb.net form to c#?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, sharpdevelop

I converted a Vb.Net Form (which was previously written in vb6) with sharpdevelop to c#,
now i am getting error that no suitable main method can be found.

Any solutions on this?

best regards

Comment: Did you convert a _Form_ or an _Application_ ?

Comment: Stupid question, but did the VB.NET application run normally at all?

Comment: @Henk Holterman A GUI Form from VB

Comment: @Mr Lister Why is this question stupid? Yes the vb.net app runs normally.

Comment: if not there, then add it buddy. Whats stopping you? I am not sure if VB.net code do have a main method.

Comment: @zenwalker: i already tried and also changed some classes to static classes with a main, but it didn´t help.

Comment: It could have been stupid, because normally programs do just run. But since this one was converted from VB6, anything was possible.

Comment: Add your converted code with the main method if that's the problem @Gobliins

Comment: First do let us know have you converted to a WinForm/WebForm/Console application in C#? If WinForm, then create Program.cs (class too) and add main method and inside that Application.Run(Winform) api. If console, then just add main and call those classes. Please do show us the code. Use pastebin if you have to.

Comment: We need more information. List the files in the converted project. Maybe as a screendump from Solution Explorer.

Comment: @zenwalker i converted a windows forms application just to c#, there was no option to choose detailed conversion types

Comment: @Henk Holterman ufApplication.vb, ufApplication.Designer.vb, uFApplication.resx, parameters.vb -> same files with .cs extension, the ufApplication is now a resources.resx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem like you'll have to fix the project, or maybe rerun the converter with different settings.

A simple way to fix could be:

- create a new WinForms project
- use Add Existing Item to add your form
- make it the main Form (Project properties)

Comment: ok it resulted in the same when i tried to copy the converted code into a c# form, lots of errors with the imported visual basic methods. Well i will try to adapt them.

Comment: ok after fixing all the errors, i could start the app with an exceptionn. The Form designer seems to have problems with some properties. Lots of "ressource xx has no property named yy" is this a bug? Because the VS code completion can access the properties.

Comment: You should have a Form1.resx _and_ a resources.resx. Maybe you can fix it back.

Comment: the ufApplication.resx is the same as the c# ressources.resx.

Comment: i figured out that only ressources with events (button_click or sth.) are affected by this

Answer (score 1):

If you created a C# Windows Forms application, you can find the Main inside Program.cs

**EDIT:** added sample code
Program.cs sample

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2

{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The process that converted VB6 to VB.NET should already have created a Windows Form.

Comment: If no Progam.cs exist with the Main method, you can try to add it manually.